# Can docker write logs to an external directory?

Tags: docker

We have written our own logger that writes about 10 different log files: skl log, http request log, a separate log for each client, etc.
If you run the service through docker, is it possible to tell him to write these logs not inside himself, but in an external folder?
From what I've read, I've only realized so far that docker only logs output to the console, and in one shared file.

Comment: read about docker volumes

Comment: I only took a quick look, but [this](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/) may be what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a docker container with volumes where you can mention your expected log directory, settings file, app resource, etc.

Here is the straightforward way to create the docker container with volumes

```
docker create --name YOUR_SERVICE_NAME -p 80:80 -v /APP_DIR_OUT_SIDE_OF_CONTAINER/settings/appsettings.json:/app/appsettings.json -v /APP_DIR_OUT_SIDE_OF_CONTAINER/Logs:/app/Logs:z YOUR_DOCKER_IMAGE_REPO_URL:IMAGE_TAG
```

Below is the docker-compose sample that should be running a container with volumes.

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  YOUR_SERVICE_NAME:
    image: IMAGE_URL
    container_name: CONTAINER_NAME
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /APP_DIR_OUT_SIDE_OF_CONTAINER/config/appsettings.json:/app/appsettings.json
      - /APP_DIR_OUT_SIDE_OF_CONTAINER/logs:/app/Logs:z

    restart: always
```

Also, you can get all possible ways to run the docker container with volumes from [Use volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)

Comment: I try it. Docker create log folder, but dont create logs files in ..

Comment: @Tidus213,
I gave you an idea based on my app's infrastructure. You might compare with your application framework and also check how/where you wrote the log and based on that you can set the volumes path.